# SnappyData per-row TTL

Tags: row, ttl, snappydata

Is it possible to set TTL per row. Meaning the row will be automatically deleted when the TTL has passed. The TTL can be different for ever row in the same table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the 'Expire' clause when you create the table. See [here](http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/programming_guide/tables_in_snappydata/).

Comment: Is Expire for the entire table? Meaning all the rows will have the same expiry. What we want is different ttl per every row.

Comment: Yes, it applies to the entire table. You will need to start a custom job that periodically executes your custom TTL logic.